# Dyno doesn't wake up on Heroku and throws H14 error

Tags: java, heroku, playframework-2.0, dyno

I have a Play Java application on Heroku and sometimes the only dyno it has goes to sleep and doesn't wake up when I access the app. Instead, I get an "Application error" and the logs say `...at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running...`. In the Dashboard the app appears as sleeping.

As far as I know an app should wake up when you access it, even if it takes longer. I should also mention that I moved the app recently from US to Europe region and I only have this problem since then.

**EDIT**

Below is the detailed log:

```
Apr 08 23:17:49 myapp heroku/web.1:  Idling 
Apr 08 23:17:49 myapp heroku/web.1:  State changed from up to down 
Apr 08 23:17:53 myapp heroku/web.1:  Stopping all processes with SIGTERM 
Apr 08 23:17:54 myapp app/web.1:  [info] play - Shutdown application default Akka system. 
Apr 08 23:17:54 myapp app/web.1:  [info] application - 201 jobs cancelled 
Apr 08 23:18:01 myapp heroku/web.1:  Process exited with status 143 
Apr 09 01:42:20 myapp heroku/router:  at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=92f438fd-d943-4585-9bc6-e04bb72a5077 fwd="86.124.196.157" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

As you can see, the dyno goes normally to sleep, but it doesn't wake up when I try to access the app.

Comment: Are you deploying with Git or with the sbt-heroku plugin?

Comment: I'm deploying with Git.

Comment: Thanks for the extra logs, that's helpful. Can you open a ticket with Heroku support so we can help you better? https://help.heroku.com

Comment: Thanks! Ticket opened.